# Unable to decrypt binary file

Tags: go, encryption, public-key-encryption, gnupg

I've been trying to encrypt `docx` file using GPG public key and go's `openpgp` library. It encrypts document but then I am unable to decrypt it using my private key.

Already tried to do the same with plain text file and decryption worked without any problems.

What am I missing here?

```go
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp"
    "bytes"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    entitylist, _ := openpgp.ReadArmoredKeyRing(bytes.NewBufferString(...))

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    w, _ := openpgp.Encrypt(buf, entitylist, nil, nil, nil)
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("in.docx")

    w.Write(b)
    w.Close()

    bts, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(buf)
    ioutil.WriteFile("out.gpg", bts, os.ModePerm)
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring errors.  Change the code to check for errors.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you encrypt the bytes before you even read the file.  You have to encrypt the bytes after you read them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys to take your time it appears that `Encode` function accepts `FileHints` struct so passing with binary from solves the problem

```
w, _ := openpgp.Encrypt(buf, entitylist, nil, &openpgp.FileHints{IsBinary: true}, nil)
```

More details on [FileHints](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp#FileHints)

```
// FileHints contains metadata about encrypted files. This metadata is, itself,
// encrypted.
type FileHints struct {
    // IsBinary can be set to hint that the contents are binary data.
    IsBinary bool
    // FileName hints at the name of the file that should be written. It's
    // truncated to 255 bytes if longer. It may be empty to suggest that the
    // file should not be written to disk. It may be equal to "_CONSOLE" to
    // suggest the data should not be written to disk.
    FileName string
    // ModTime contains the modification time of the file, or the zero time if not applicable.
    ModTime time.Time
}
```

Thanks.